# Как переопределить папку статичного контента ASP.NET Core + nginx?

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core

Есть ASP.NET Core приложения на нём висят N сайтов.
У каждого сайта своё шаблон, и статичный контент для этого шаблона лежит по адресу

```
wwwroot/site1/img/background.png
wwwroot/site2/img/background.png
wwwroot/site3/img/background.png
```

Следовательно в коде страницы путь будет

```
/site1/img/background.png
/site2/img/background.png
/site3/img/background.png
```

Мне нужно переопределить папки `site*` что бы при заходе к примеру на сайт `site3.com`
в исходном коде страницы путь к картинке был `/img/background.png` но саму картинку нужно искать и возвращать по пути `/site3/img/background.png` где `site3` адрес на который зашёл человек.
Как мне это сделать?
Nginx конфиг стандартный

```html
http {
  map $http_connection $connection_upgrade {
    "~*Upgrade" $http_connection;
    default keep-alive;
  }

  server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   _;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }
}
```